# Drop group of duplicates that appear after first group

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

```
index   name   value
0       John   Foo
1       John   Bar
2       John   Bar
3       John   Foo
4       Jane   Foo
5       Jane   Bar
6       Jane   Bar
7       John   Foo
8       John   Bar
```

I'm trying to drop all occurrences of `John` after the first group in which the name appears, so that the data looks like:

```
index   name   value
0       John   Foo
1       John   Bar
2       John   Bar
3       John   Foo
4       Jane   Foo
5       Jane   Bar
6       Jane   Bar
```

Of course, using `df.drop_duplicates(['name'])` would only keep one row per name. I know there are ways to solve this by cobbling together for loops, but is there a Pandas-specific way to drop duplicate values that appear after continuous rows of a specific value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a helper column, `'ng'`, that defines consecutive groups of `name`, then keep only the first group for each name: (Helper column left in for illustration)

```
df['ng'] = df.groupby(df.name.ne(df.name.shift(1)).cumsum()).ngroup()
df[df.groupby('name').ng.transform('min') == df.ng]

   name value  ng
0  John   Foo   0
1  John   Bar   0
2  John   Bar   0
3  John   Foo   0
4  Jane   Foo   1
5  Jane   Bar   1
6  Jane   Bar   1
```